# TIme based Leaderboards?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

I am wanting to create leader boards that exists for 1 week.  After 1 week the users can collect prizes based on rank.  Once a prize is collected they are then placed into the next weeks leader board race.

I have a couple of issues I can not find a solution for do to my lack of knowledge with database structures, firebase, and .indexOn.

My first attempt was to create nested data under the week the leader board was created so for example (mm,dd,yyyy) "highscores/9,1,2017" would be one week, and so on adding 7 days each time.  A huge problem I ran into was indexing over this information.  I could not figure out a way to write a rule in my Firebase console to sort "score" under "highscore"/"random_data_string"/["score"].  After a long time of looking I believe the answer is you can not sort a nested value?  Another reason this failed for me was do to the fact that it would create massive amounts of entry points under "highscore" over time, and not being able to use index on any of them would ultimately be unbearably slow (A guess since the manual says to use index to speed up the process as data grows).

My second attempt was to create two leader board with "01" and "02" appended to the end of the path name, respectively, as shown in the code below.  The idea here was to jump back and forth with the leader boards so users who took a few days to sign on and claim their reward for the previous week had 6 days to do so.

```
public string FirebaseHighscoresPath(bool current)
{
    if ( ( System.DateTime.Today.AddDays( DaysTilNextTournament() ).DayOfYear - 1 ) % 14 < 7 )
        return current ? "highscores01" : "highscores02";
    else
        return current ? "highscores02" : "highscores01";
}
```

Here is where my new issue stems from.  How might I delete the entries of the previous leader board before its time is up and is needed to be converted to the "current" leader board?  In the past I had server code I could play with, but with firebase it's very hands off.  I need a solution that requires the client to process this information.  I don't want 50 clients to tell firebase to purge an old leader board all at once.  This would most certainly lead to corrupted data.  I also do not want the clients to start telling the previous leader board to purge the day before, because if I have 1,000 users on that day, the leader board could have been told to purge 1,000 times.  This feels like a massive waste of bandwidth, and server cycles.

Lastly, I would like to know if I am even going about this the correct way.  With all the research I've done over the past week trying to get this finished I found a Push() function that seems to have a feature to sort by date created.  But that's as much info I could find on this.  The learning curve for all this is very high, and I'm purely self taught from trial and error, so my methods are learned by accident, or by a well written out guide online.

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to provide backend logic so your clients don't have to somehow collaborate on a solution.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/  You can create a recurring function that periodically does the maintenance.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you very much for providing links